# Grails redirect looping error when rendering view with the same name as action

Tags: grails, groovy, infinite-loop, http-redirect

I am using Grails 2.2.3 for an app to clear out Duplicate persons in our Database. When I attempt to access a controller action, I am receiving the following error:

`Error Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.exceptions.CannotRedirectException: Cannot issue a redirect(..) here. A previous call to redirect(..) has already redirected the response.`

It looks like an infinite redirect loop, because the Stacktrace in the console just goes bonkers as soon as I go to the `duplicate()` action. It keeps printing until I `Ctrl+C` out of the console. Also, there are multiple screens for working with a Duplicate and fixing it, which is why I am giving a way to store the "working" Duplicate.

The controller actions:

- **`setWorkingDuplicate`** - set a duplicate to work with on each page (so a user doesn't have to keep typing it in).
- **`duplicate`** - view a duplicate or, if there is no `session.id,` present the user with find duplicate form
- **`getDuplicate`** (action only) - gets a duplicate and renders the duplicate page

The error is occurring when I go straight to the duplicate() page. If I set the working duplicate first, no redirect issues happen.

Here are the controller actions that are causing the issue.

```
def setWorkingDuplicate(Integer id) {
    if (id && Duplicate.get(id)) {
        session.id = id
        flash.message = "Working Duplicate set to ID ${id}"
        redirect action: 'getDuplicate', params: [id: session.id]
    }
}

def duplicate() {
    if (session.id) {
        redirect(action: 'getDuplicate', params: [id: session.id])
        return
    }
    render view: 'duplicate'
}

def getDuplicate(Integer id) {
    def duplicate = Duplicate.get(id)

    if (!duplicate) {
        flash.message = "Duplicate not found with ID ${id}."
        render(view: 'duplicate')
        return
    }

    render view: 'duplicate', model: [duplicate: duplicate]
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Edit: it looks like somewhere down in the stack trace I am also receiving the following errors.

```
Error Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

and

```
WARN: Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

And in the stack trace, the following errors keep repeating over and over:

```
| Error     at edu.mssu.duplicates.InitialStepsController.render(InitialStepsController.groovy)
| Error     at edu.mssu.duplicates.InitialStepsController$render.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
| Error     at edu.mssu.duplicates.InitialStepsController.getDuplicate(InitialStepsController.groovy:69)
| Error     at edu.mssu.duplicates.InitialStepsController.getDuplicate(InitialStepsController.groovy)
| Error     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor382.invoke(Unknown Source)
| Error     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
| Error     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
| Error     at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap.get(BeanMap.java:390)
| Error     at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap$12.next(BeanMap.java:565)
| Error     at org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.UnmodifiableIterator.next(UnmodifiableIterator.java:72)
| Error     at java.util.HashMap.putAll(HashMap.java:621)
| Error     at org.springframework.ui.ModelMap.addAllAttributes(ModelMap.java:117)
| Error     at org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView.<init>(ModelAndView.java:97)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.RenderDynamicMethod.renderView(RenderDynamicMethod.java:485)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.RenderDynamicMethod.invoke(RenderDynamicMethod.java:187)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersApi.invokeRender(ControllersApi.java:258)
| Error     at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersApi.render(ControllersApi.java:246)
```

This is a (very stripped down) version of my Duplicate GSP. The GSP presents a way to quickly search/show/update a Duplicate and display that Duplicate, all in one page. Hence the search box and show form.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Duplicate</h1>
        <g:form action="duplicate" method="POST">
            <label for="id">Duplicate ID</label> <g:textField name="id" value="${duplicate?.id}" />

            <g:submitButton name="btnRetrieveDuplicate" value="Retrieve Duplicate" />
        </g:form>

        <g:if test="${duplicate}">
            <g:form action="updateDuplicate" method="POST">
                //Form stuff

                <g:hiddenField name="id" value="${duplicate?.id}" />
            </g:form>
        </g:if>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try not to use `session.id`, make it session.myid or something to store your internal id. Also, make sure to cleanup that value when you are done with it. Might cause you more issues as it stays all time for that session.

Comment: do you have your own `InitialStepsController.render`? what is inside your gsp (view `duplicate`)

Comment: Hey @IgorArtamonov. I don't have a render() action. Also, I am adding my duplicate GSP in my question. The problem does appear to be in the render method, though. Removing render makes the error go away... Still, I don't want the problem to just go away, I want to understand why there is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've had some really strange issues before when naming controllers matched some other objects or started with 'get'

Try renaming:
    `def getDuplicate(Integer id)`
to something completely different like: `def myDupe(Integer id)`

Sorry I can't give you a better explanation, but I've done this a few times just to get things working.

Comment: I have also had some problems when naming controller methods with get, try changing it to something else