# Grails <g: remoteLink> rendering content multiple times

Tags: ajax, grails

I want to be able to click on an object in my page and load a table to another part of the page. When I click on the remote link that I created, it loads hundreds of tables instead of just one.

My controller method:

```
def getGroupOverview(){
    render template:'templates/groupOverviews/north'
}
```

My gsp code calling this method:

```
<td><g:remoteLink action="getGroupOverview" update="group-overview">North</g:remoteLink></td>
```

My target location:

```
<div id="group-overview" class="col-sm-4 well"></div>
```

My template being called to be rendered:

```
<h4>North Overview</h4>

<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed tree">
<thead>
    <tr class="treegrid-1">
        <th>Group/Desk/Prefix</th>
        <th>Current</th>
        <th>Future</th>
        <th>>50</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    <tr class="treegrid-2 treegrid-level-1">
        <td>46</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="treegrid-3 treegrid-level-1">
        <td>53</td>
        <td>168</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I also get this error several hundred times in my console:

```
Error |
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap.get(BeanMap.java:390)
Error |
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap$12.next(BeanMap.java:565)
Error |
at   org.apache.commons.collections.iterators.UnmodifiableIterator.next(UnmodifiableIterator.java:72)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageBinding.addMap(GroovyPageBinding.java:213)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.createBinding(GroovyPageWritable.java:259)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages.GroovyPageWritable.writeTo(GroovyPageWritable.java:165)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.RenderDynamicMethod.renderTemplate(RenderDynamicMethod.java:440)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.RenderDynamicMethod.invoke(RenderDynamicMethod.java:212)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersApi.invokeRender(ControllersApi.java:309)
Error |
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.api.ControllersApi.render(ControllersApi.java:297)
Error |
at ticketreport.TicketReportController.render(TicketReportController.groovy)
Error |
at ticketreport.TicketReportController$render.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
Error |
at ticketreport.TicketReportController.getGroupOverview(TicketReportController.groovy:9)
Error |
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor248.invoke(Unknown Source)
Error |
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error |
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Error |
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I found a solution. In grails, it is not recommended to begin a method name with 'get' in a controller. So my 'getGroupOverveiw' violated this rule. It explains the Java Reflection error, and when I changed it to 'groupOverview', it got rid of the error and the content being displayed more than once.

This question is the one I used to find the solution: [Grails redirect looping error when rendering view with the same name as action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882665/grails-redirect-looping-error-when-rendering-view-with-the-same-name-as-action)

I'm not sure on the specifics of why it caused it to create hundreds of instances of my templates, but I know it fixed the problem.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: You are including a javascript library like jquery on your page, yes? That will be required for this to work. Somewhere you should have `<g:javascript library="jquery" />` or `<r:require module="jquery" />`

Comment: Yes I tried both and neither helped. Originally, I was just using this: '<g:external dir="/js" file="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />'

**edit**: I should mention that it works if I simply try to render some text, so I think the issue might be with the render line in my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. In grails, it is not recommended to begin a method name with 'get' in a controller. So my 'getGroupOverveiw' violated this rule. It explains the Java Reflection error, and when I changed it to 'groupOverview', it got rid of the error and the content being displayed more than once.

This question is the one I used to find the solution: Grails redirect looping error when rendering view with the same name as action

I'm not sure on the specifics of why it caused it to create hundreds of instances of my templates, but I know it fixed the problem.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

```
at ticketreport.TicketReportController.render(TicketReportController.groovy)
```

is this the controller doing the rendering ?

```
'templates/groupOverviews/north'
```

is this path available from the current path of your controller ? i.e. templates/ I would suggest trying

> '/templates/groupOverviews/north'

if it is from the root of your views folder.